# How to create a circular button that recesses when pressed (Swift)

Tags: swift, uibutton

How do I create a circular button that has a recessed look (down into the screen) when pressed? I see NSRecessedBezelStyle NSButton but that’s a rectangular button whose size is tied to the text. Animating the push down into recessed form would be cool but not absolutely essential.

Comment: Make an image for the button unrecessed and an image for the button recessed and use them as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UIButton. Set the cornerRadius to (button height / 2). Style it for each state you would like. You could even use an image as a background and just edit the image for pressed and not pressed. Use Interface Builder and set the background image as applicable.